# How to find an element having an attribute of unknown value using BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

This is how it is done when attribute value we are looking for is known:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulStoneSoup
soup = BeautifulStoneSoup(html, 'html.parser')
found_elems = soup.find_all(attrs={"myattribute" : "myknownvalue"})
```

How do I find all elements with "myattribute" attribute, not knowing it's value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't know value of attribute, set it to `True`:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulStoneSoup
soup = BeautifulStoneSoup(html, 'html.parser')
found_elems = soup.find_all(attrs={"myattribute": True})
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to use CSS selector:

```
found_elems = soup.select('[myattribute]')
```

More on CSS selectors [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp).